# Query that compares dates

Tags: database-design, ms-access, table

I'm trying to create a query that shows if students are mature or not, based on their date of birth. However when the query is executed it returns all students as not mature. Any students that are born before 1/10/1971 should be classed as mature.

Shown below is the `IIf()` statement I have used to show if students are mature.

[image]

When executed the table returns the following results

[image]

Can anyone give any idea as to why this is happening?

Shown below is the full page of the Query

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the query and the RDBMS that you are using?

Comment: My appoligies, the RDBMS is microsoft access and I've updated the question with the full page of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely because the expression `1/10/1971` is interpreted as a numeric expression, i.e. `1 divided by 10 divided by 1971` which is 0 (with integer division rounding values down). Telling Access that this is a date can be done using quotes (not really recommended) or by using a date function, like this:

```
IIf([DOB]<DateSerial(1971, 10, 1), "Mature", "Not mature")
```

The above `DateSerial()` VBA function will return October 1, 1971. The parameters are `(Year, Month, Day)`.

Also, the following will work (thanks, @ypercube!)

```
IIf([DOB]<#1971-10-01#, "Mature", "Not mature")
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about the quotes. The data type of DOB is Date/Time. I am now getting a "#error" in all of the cells of the Mature field =/ any other ideas? And my apologies the RDBMS I am using is Access.

Comment: I've updated my answer using the VBA function `DateSerial()` which should be available in MS Access. Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I think this format works always for date literals in Access and is unambiguous: `#yyyy-mm-dd#` `#1971-01-10#` (can't remember if it has be single-quoted as well or not.)

Comment: Dates enclosed in ## must not be quoted, it is a special data designation.